# How to handle legacy SQL database structure?

Tags: sql, database, web-applications, architecture, logic

I have to reimplement an application which is using a database with a bad structure of tables.

The tables have a primary key but they don't use any foreign keys. Everything is 'controlled' by the application logic.

But I can't normalize the tables because they are used by another application which fills the tables.

Is there a possibility to implement an abstraction layer in my new application to simplify the database access?

Comment: Try using Views.

Comment: But what if I want to store data back to the database? For that case the SQL View is not suitable.

Comment: You don't mention which database you are using, but on most of them you can update views if the views are created according to a few guidelines. The most important one, is that the view must include the PK and have a 1:1 relationship with the underlying table(s). Check your specific database for the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Data Access Layer, or a Repository pattern will create a nice abstraction over your database that you can program to, and hide the ugliness of that database design.  Then you can pretend that there is a nice, clean, normalized structure underneath.  It also gives you the opportunity to enforce some of that referential integrity, and create compensating behaviors when it is violated (throwing exceptions, excluding orphan children, etc).